# Socket.io serve 404 for non-socket.io urls

Tags: node.js, socket.io

We have some kind of chat app using nodejs and socket.io as server. Client is just a regular PHP based app. It is working quite well.

However, we would like to serve 404 errors for URLs not associated with the socket.io app, like the base url, favicon.ico and the rest of the urls.

For example, the server is at:

```
https://awesome-messenger.com
```

and the usual socket.io url is at:

```
https://awesome-messenger.com/socket.io/*
```

We would like to throw 404 to anything else not handled by socket.io.

Current setup:

- nodejs 6.x
- socket.io latest

Sample code (messenger.js):

```
var app = require('http').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(4040);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('joinRoom', function(data){
        socket.join(data.room);
    });

    // Other codes here...
});
```

Started by:

```
node /path/to/messenger.js
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you get when you request a resource that isn't handled by socket.io?

Comment: It just hangs up, until nginx times out. Just found out that I can use expressJS to handle 404. http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ I'll try it first and I'll update this.

Answer (score 0):

We used express + socket.io instead to serve a custom homepage and throw 404 errors on non-socket.io urls. I got the idea from here: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

```
var app = require('express')(),
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('joinRoom', function(data){
        socket.join(data.room);
    });

    // Other codes
});

http.listen(4040, function () {
    console.log('Listening on *:4040');
});
```

So if we access something like: /favicon.ico or /foo/bar, it will throw a simple 404 error.